# For integrable function $f $, $\int_{E_n}f d\mu\rightarrow 0$ where $E_n=\{x:f(x) > n\} $

Tags: measure-theory

Given $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is measurable and integrable function. Define $E_n=\{x:f(x) > n\}$. Then I need to show $\int_{E_n} f d\mu \rightarrow0$.

Looking for some hint. Actually by contradiction we can show that measure of $E_n$ goes to $0$.Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Use dominated convergence theorem

Comment: what will be the sequence of function? can you please elaborate a bit

Comment: $f1_{E_n} \to 0$ pointwise

Answer (score 2):

Note that $E_n^c=\{|f|\leq n\}$ is increasing, and therefore, 
$$
|f|1_{E_n^c}\  \ \mbox{is non-negative and increasing to}\ \ |f|.  
$$
By MCT, we have 
$$
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{E_n^c}|f|d\mu= \int |f|d\mu<\infty.
$$ 
Thus, we have 
$$
|\int_{E_n}f d\mu|\leq \int_{E_n}|f|d\mu=\int |f|d\mu-\int_{E_n^c}|f|d\mu \rightarrow 0.
$$